I'm trying to create an Library management system and not getting why there's a loop in switch case with break statement too
I've not added any features yet in this program and only added some tasks in "1)Create an account" while in this code block when you enter your name after pressing enter, it starts looping infnitely even after using "break;" it won't stop.
here's the code
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


int login_as;
int i = 3;
int std_choice;
int std_deposit;

void student() {
    char std_name;
    int std_age;
    int s = 6;
    while (s != std_choice) {
        cout << "1) Create an account\n2) View balance\n3)Purchase a Book\n4)Rent a Book\n5)Return a book\n6) Login Screen" << endl;
        cin >> std_choice;
        switch (std_choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "REGISTER!" << endl;
            cout << "Enter Name:\n" << endl; //after this line it starts looping and wont break//
            cin >> std_name;
            cout << "Age: \n" << endl;
            cin >> std_age;
            cout << "Please deposit 10$ as initial deposit!\n1)Yes\n2)No" << endl;
            cout << "curl qreno.de/https://www.google.com" << endl;
            cin >> std_deposit;
            break;
        
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}


int main() {
    while (i != login_as ){
        cout << "Login as:\n1) User\n2) Librarian\n3) Exit" << endl;
        cin >> login_as;
        student();
    }
    
    return 0;
}

I'm avoiding asking chatgpt or phind as it would straight forwardly show me the solution, i want it to see from the human perspective.
I was expecting it would print the statements one by one after entering the input

Those breaks get you out of the switch, not the while loop.

OT: Why all those global variables? Do they really need to be global? Like for example login_as which is  not used by the student function. And prefixing your variables with std_ makes them seem very similar to things in the std namespace.

The code does not check for input failure.  For example, if (!(cin >> std_name)) throw "input error"; for every input.  I suspect the problem is that you are entering a name that is longer than a single char.  (But since you did not provide the input that you are using, that's just a guess.)

Side notes : #include <stdlib.h> this is a "C" header file and not needed, use .  Using using namespace std; is not recommended and for strings (like the name of the student) use std::string not char

And no ChatGPT will not show you a straightforward solution... ChatGPT is really not good at C++, it might show something that looks like C++ but often is subtly (or not so subtly) wrong. so don't trust that

@Eljay thanks, i forgot to use string instead of char

you have used a char datatype for the variable std_name which is used to store the name the user inputs. cin >> std_name could break your code if you enter more than one character (as mentioned by @Eljay), since your trying to store multiple characters in a variable that is meant to store a single character.
To fix this, change the datatype of std_name to std::string e.g.
string std_name;

a char* alone cannot store a string. They would need to allocate memory for the string too. std::cin doesnt do that

Ok, thanks. changing my answer to only std::string now
